How to consume all yielded elements into an array?
I have a Ruby object that has a each method. Now, I would like to fetch the yielded elements into an array. I'm doing this:
array = []
x.each do |i|
  array << i
end

Is it possible to do this in one line? Something like:
array = to_array(x)

Is there a function in Ruby like to_array? I know, I can write it myself, but maybe it already exists? I need it in every project.

Given a class with a simple each method:
class Foo
  def each
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

You can turn such method (one yielding elements, the name doesn't really matter) into an enumerator via to_enum or its alias enum_for. They take a method name which defaults to :each. The returned Enumerator in turn includes Enumerable which provides to_a:
x = Foo.new

x.to_enum
#=> #<Enumerator: #<Foo:0x000000010e104820>:each>

x.to_enum.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3]

A common Ruby idiom is to return such enumerator right from within the method if no block is given:
class Foo
  def each
    return to_enum(__method__) unless block_given?

    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  end
end

__method__ returns the current method's name as a symbol, i.e. :each in the above code.
Usage:
x = Foo.new

x.each
#=> #<Enumerator: #<Foo:0x0000000120212c00>:each>

x.each.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3]

Of course, you're not limited to to_a, you can call any Enumerator / Enumerable method that way:
x.each.select(&:odd?)
#=> [1, 3]

x.each.sum
#=> 6

while retaining the block behavior:
x.each do |i|
  puts i
end
# 1
# 2
# 3
#=> nil


If Foo implements #each just have it include the Enumerable mixin. This gives access to a whole host of useful methods, including #to_a.
E.g.
class Foo
   include Enumerable

   def each
     (1..9).each { |x| yield x }
   end
end

Foo.new.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

You can modify the class without directly modifying the code where the class is defined.
class Foo
  include Enumerable
end

Otherwise defining such a method is easy, but mixing in Enumerable is easier.
def baz(z)
  arr = []
  z.each { |x| arr << x }
  arr
end

You can also extend an instance of a class with a mixin. E.g.
class A
   def each
     (1..7).each { |x| yield x }
   end
end
a = A.new
a.to_a
# NoMethodError (undefined method `to_a' for #<A:0x00007fffe82be680>)
a.extend(Enumerable)
a.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A.new.to_a
# NoMethodError (undefined method `to_a' for #<A:0x00007fffe846ac18>)

Since #extend returns the object it's extended, your one-liner is:
arr = x.extend(Enumerable).to_a

Note that this works for any mixin, even the following thoroughly ridiculous example.
class Foo
  def foo
    puts "bar"
  end
end

module FooFoo
  def foo_foo
    2.times { foo }
  end
end

Foo.new.foo_foo
#  undefined method `foo_foo' for #<Foo:0x00000001084a3d38> (NoMethodError)

Foo.new.extend(FooFoo).foo_foo
# bar
# bar       


I know, but I said in the question: I DON'T want to modify the class anyhow

In my case, I don't even have a class, i have a variable that has .each method. I need to fetch everything from it, making an array. I should probably change the question description.

You are right, I can create such a function, but I need it in every project. This is why I'm looking for an already existing one, which I can use everywhere.

There you go: x.extend(Enumerable).to_a. The rest of the answer, I believe, you can remove :) Thanks a lot!


Is it possible to do this in one line?

Line breaks are optional in Ruby. They can always be replaced with either a semicolon, a keyword, or just horizontal whitespace.
Therefore, it is always possible to do anything and everything in Ruby in one line, by simply removing the line breaks:
array = []; x.each do |i| array << i end

